Unable to register Log4j shutdown hook because JVM is shutting down. Using SimpleLogger
I have started trino but the hive-metastore-1 keep exited after few seconds in docker. The logs are showing as below:
2024-07-10 06:56:24,321 shutdown-hook-0 INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
2024-07-10 06:56:24,323 shutdown-hook-0 INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
2024-07-10 06:56:24,332 shutdown-hook-0 WARN Unable to register Log4j shutdown hook because JVM is shutting down. Using SimpleLogger

How should I debug it? I have tried searching online but no solution so far.
